# HTTPS referrer policy problems

Tags: python, http, tcp, request

I need to do a request to a server with Python, I'm using the `requests` library. The point is that I get always a Forbbiden error(403).

I watched the request that my chrome makes, and I see something that I think is causing the trouble. The thing is that has this thing in the request (of chrome): Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin.

I don't know if is this or not, but if it is, how can I solve this?

Here is the code of the request:

```
import requests

s = requests.Session()

req = s.request(
    method='GET',
    url='(HERE IS THE URL)', 
)
```

This is what I get if I print the result (req.text):

```html
<html>
<head><title>403 Forbidden</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>403 Forbidden</h1></center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: *"The thing is that has this thing in the request (of chrome): Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin."* - this is very likely not the cause of your problem. There are many differences between requests done by the browser and done by Python and I don't know what makes you think that specifically this difference is causing issues. My guess is that the server is behind some CDN (Cloudflare, Akamai, Fastly, ...) with bot protection and that you run into this bot protection. There is no generic solutions, but with more details like the specific URL one can try to help better.

Comment: Ok ty. I will revise. The thing is that I don't think they are using some CDN(At least Cloudflare). I only need to automate some downloads. I don't know if there is another way to do it, but I will see if there is a chance to do it with some chrome extension. Apart from that, I don't understand what are the differences between python done requests and browser done. I will find some information because I am so new in this. Thank you a lot.